# Grouping to name based off similar values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to compare two datasets and if they have a match then they should be categorised.
For example,

Dataset1.JSON: contains latitude and longitude data
ControlData.JSON: is a control dataset which contains a device name, id and also has latitude and longitude data

Like this:

Dataset1:

```
    "lat": 12,
    "lon": 13,
    "lat": 14,
    "lon": 15,

And so on....
```

ControlData:

```
{"id":1,"name":"A","lat":12,"lon":13}
{"id":2,"name":"B","lat":14,"lon":15}
```

What I want to do is, run through the Dataset1.json and match all the 'lat' and 'lon' with the ControlData's 'lat' and 'lon' and once its been matched, it should be grouped by name and id

Ideal Output

```
Name ID   lat     lon
A    1    12        13
B    2    14        15
```

It's not just a simple print ControlData as it has the the attributes I want printed. I need to run through all JSON and match them by lat and lon so I can associate them with its correct name.

I hope that makes sense.

I havent found a suitable solution yet.

Comment: Have you explode your json?

Comment: Have you done any work on json? Is this the raw version of the json data?

Comment: this is a simplified version of the json file. The actual JSON file contains 5000 lines of data, but I am focusing on the lat and lon

Comment: Each key in a dictionary / json should be unique. But in your example, there are data with the same key. Are there duplicate keys in the raw json data?

Comment: Dataset1 contains attributes such as cityname, station, lat,long, temp, windspeed etc and the ControlData only contains those attributes above. What I need to do is basically display both tables and if the ‘lat’ and ‘lon’ from Dataset1 match the lat and lon from the controlData file it should group it by it’s name and id. Essentially I need to read thru all JSON files and match all lat and lon to the controlData